# How to create chef databags with chef-vault

Tags: json, windows, chef-infra, databags, chef-vault

I want to create a databag with credentials of servers which needs to be encrypted.
Do I need to create chef-vault first ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this https://blog.chef.io/2016/01/21/chef-vault-what-is-it-and-what-can-it-do-for-you/ will help you. When it comes to editing a vault, I would rather delete and recreate a vault than edit it as it's easy to do.